# failed to resolve com.android.support.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2

Tags: android-studio, compiler-errors, android-gradle-plugin

I've just downloaded android studio for the first time and i'm getting gradle errors. I've downloaded everything the SDK provided and still the same errors.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.noelly.myapplication"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.+'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

The errors I'm getting are

```
  (Failed to resolve: com.android.support.appcompat-v7:25.+)
```

and

```
(Failed to resolve: com.android.support.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2)
```

Everything by the way is up to date,please help this is really frustrating starting out.

**EDIT FROM ANSWER ONE- PICTURE OF INSTALLED TOOLS---
[sdktoolsscreenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vL2D.png)

Code form project build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

New Error messages_____[newerrorscreenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1eZqo.png)

Comment: Do you really need those testing libraries? (espresso and junit)

Comment: I Get even more errors if I remove them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how your gradle file should look like:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.noelly.myapplication"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
}
```

**Update:**
There must be a problem with the SDK you downloaded. Navigate to C:/Users/Noelly/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android and delete the `support` folder.

Now open your SDK Manager and re-install the Android Support Repository.

Comment: Are you sure you downloaded the Android Support Library SDK? Can you post a screenshot of your Android SDK Manager showing the Installed Tools?

Comment: I posted a link to screenshot-

Comment: ^At the bottom of original post

Comment: Maybe you should specify the full version number 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'

Comment: Iv'e already tried, it replaces the error message with the version i edited.

Comment: I can see on the screenshot that you have the option "Install repository and sync project". What happens if you do that?

Comment: It actually does nothing- it lags me for a few seconds like it did something, but then returns to normal. And i literally have everything on the sdk installed, so idk what it would install.

Comment: Right. Try closing Android Studio and running it as Administrator. And if that doesn't work, please post your build.gradle from the Project module (open the gradle scripts tab on the left and you'll see it)

Comment: Didn't work as admin- posted the project build.gradle

Comment: This is weird. ⊙_ʘ

Comment: And does it work if you remove the appcompat dependency?

Comment: Haha i knooowwwww- I get 10 more errors removing appcompat

Comment: Maybe its another problem having to do with file locations or something, could i like contact you somewhere else? I really want this gradle to work, its making me a very sad person hahah

Comment: Rosario- look at my new screenshot- i think it has more info on the error messages

Comment: Haha, sure. Where else are you? Facebook? Twitter? Telegram? WhatsApp? And I've just noticed you have a "return void" on your gradle file. Why?

Comment: It gets rid of a highlight on the } bracket below it, but with or without it doesnt affect my error messeges, i thought id try to do something to make progress haha. Why this gotta be so complicated, i just wanted to learn how to make apps Xc. And i have an instagram and a facebook-

Comment: sent- im mockingbird-

Answer (score 5):

> failed to resolve com.android.support.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2

This error can occur when we refactor layout name.

I had the same problem and my mistake was that I had created the layout naming **test.xml** and then when I refactored that name with like **layout_offers.xml**, my gradle was changed something like

---

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.detail_layout.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    })
```

---

**Whereas It should be like follow**

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
```

So, one solution is that we should avoid using **test.xml** as a layout name.

Answer (score 0):

I got this same error message after renaming a layout file, although everything had just worked before. I fixed this by commenting out these lines from gradle:

```
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.detail_layout.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
```

I have no idea why this happened or if this is a good way of fixing it, only hoping that this could be a quick fix for some beginner like me.

Answer (score 0):

I got same trouble as yours, and I have found how to solve the problem.
It was because I was using x86 operating system, while android studio was x64.
I went to https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html and pressed 'download option', and installed x86 version of android studio.
Do not uninstall your previous x64 android studio. It is required because of the android sdk.
unpack your x86 android studio anywhere, and find 'bin' folder. There should be your 'studio.exe'.